# How to optimize array lookup of JS object based on one property

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

We have a large array of objects:

```
var englishStudents = [
    {StudentId: 1, Name: "John"},
    {StudentId: 2, Name: "Jack"},
    {StudentId: 3, Name: "Jane"}
];
```

Need to check if another similar object is contained in this array, just by comparing one property alone.

```
var randomStudent = {StudentId: 1337, Name: "Foo"};
```

This is what I have, and it seems as though it will work, but I don't think this is the best way to do this.

```
var studentIds = $.map(englishStudents, function (student, index) { return student.StudentId; });
var randomStudentLearnsEnglish = false;
for (var sId in studentIds) {
    if (randomStudent.StudentId == sId) {
        randomStudentLearnsEnglish = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

What would be the optimized way to do this?

Comment: That seems efficient enough. Are you having performance issues?

Comment: Is the array sorted? Is there a reason they're in an array, and not in something keyed by the ID?

Comment: @elclanrs: I was looking to make the two loops in there to one, somehow.

Comment: @DaveNewton: It is an unsorted array.

Comment: @FloydPink Then unless you have some form of backing index, iteration is the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to know is if the ID exists can do this:

```
function checkIdExists( id){
    /* map array of matching ID, if none exists length of array is zero*/
    return  $.map(englishStudents, function (student, index) { 
               return student.StudentId==id; 
    }).get().length;
});
```

Use:

```
 if( checkIdExists( 1234)){
     /* run exists code*/
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I want. Although after looking at this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9283885/218882), I feel $.grep() would be faster, but maybe they're the same.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep student data in a hash table like [JHashtable](http://www.timdown.co.uk/jshashtable/) instead of the array. For mor complex scenarios, you can maintain more than one hash table, like `studentsById`, `studentsByCountryCode`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a hash instead of an array, so:

```
var englishStudents = {
    1: {StudentId: 1, Name: "John"},
    2: {StudentId: 2, Name: "Jack"},
    3: {StudentId: 3, Name: "Jane"}
};
```

and then to retrieve, simply do:

```
var student = englishStudents[id];
```

Comment: your object syntax is invalid

Answer (score 1):

If you really want, you can create a further indexing scheme:

```
var englishStudents = [
    {StudentId: 1, Name: "John"},
    {StudentId: 2, Name: "Jack"},
    {StudentId: 3, Name: "Jane"}
];
 //if doing this a lot of time, take the one time hit of construction and memory
var idToNameMap = createIdToNameMap(englishStudents); //returns {'1': 'John', '2': Jack' , '3': 'Jane'}

var randomStudent = getRandomStudent();
if( idToNameMap[ randomStudent.StudentId] != undefined){ ... }
```